# Looking to save word document as PDF with text from document as the file name

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

There are hundreds of contracts in .doc format that I need to save as pdf.

I am hoping to use a macro to quickly save the document as pdf using the first and last name of the person who the document was addressed to [always 2nd line of 'table' that is 1x1 -so the entire length of document]

So I think the logic would go:

1. Move Cursor to correct location
2. Select 2 words to right [i.e. first & last name]
3. Copy those words
4. Some how concatenate those words at the end of the desired filepath of a Save As statement, but before the .pdf file extension.

Comment: You'll need to identify the table.  You can then get the text from the table and store it in a variable.  Then make your SaveAs command using the variable as your file name.

Comment: Your question as written is too broad. Break it into separate tasks, and start figuring out the tasks individually. First figure out how to select the table and retrieve the text from the cells. Then add string handling (retrieving the filename without extension, concatenating the text from the table, and then concatenating the .pdf extension). Then add saving a file from VBA code. Recording a macro in Word itself will do the majority of the work for you.

Comment: You know you could work with formfields or bookmarks which you could set into your table to retrieve data faster.